# Video.js : canvas or css?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, video.js

I am making new skins for my video player with video.js. What is the best way to personalize it :

- use canvas ?
- use css ?

I have to make 4 differents skins.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple and use CSS, especially if you have to make a few different skins. We've even got a designer you can use to see a live preview, and it uses LESS to boot so you get nice variables and things like that (not to mention reference implementation).

[Video.js Designer](http://designer.videojs.com/)

When you get done, we'd love to showcase the skins on our Wiki...keep us updated on how things go.

Comment: Hello Matt, thank you for aswering me :). I am a beginner in javascript so I need a little help ^^'.
I have to add a lot of components like : HD, Twitter, Facebook button. Do I have to generate the HTML code in the javascript with the prototypes things ?
Maybe do you have an exemple of how to add items ?

Comment: There's a [plugin](https://github.com/brianpkelley/video-js-4-plugins/tree/master/addThis) for "AddThis" that might be a good example for what you're looking to do.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it today. I keep you in touch. :)